# Problem creating subreports in iReport

Tags: ireport

I have created a report which contains a subreport.
This subreport in turn contains two more subreports and each of them display a graph.

When I preview the main report it loads partially and incomplete, however each subreport previews perfectly fine.

Why is this happening and what is the solution for it?

I am using iReport 3.7 professional.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you have kept the sub reports in your page and proper alignment.

Also please check that there should be a query which returns some values in your main report and as well as in your sub reports.